# python win32api(win32ui) draw dash line not working

Tags: c#, python, c++, winapi, pywin32

```
#-*- coding=utf-8 -*-
import win32ui ,win32gui
import win32print 
import win32con   
from win32api import RGB
from PIL import Image, ImageWin

hDC = win32ui.CreateDC()  
hDC.CreatePrinterDC(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()) 
hDC.StartDoc ("Test doc") 
hDC.StartPage ()  
hDC.SetMapMode (win32con.MM_TWIPS) 
pen = win32ui.CreatePen(win32con.PS_DASH, 1, RGB(148, 37, 37))
hDC.SetBkMode(win32con.TRANSPARENT)
hDC.SelectObject(pen)
hDC.MoveTo(1000, -1000)
hDC.LineTo( 1000, -10000 )
hDC.EndPage() 
hDC.EndDoc()
```

PS_DASH,PS_DOT,PS_DASHDOTDOT not working? why? help me!
if set devmode paperSize = DMPAPER_A4, width not working too;
win32ui.CreatePen(win32con.PS_DASH, 1, RGB(148, 37, 37))
code run xp